# Trying to decompile hex firmware

Tags: disassembly, firmware

I managed to get the firmware for my IoT device but the firmware is in HEX. What is the best way to convert it to a binary so I can use binwalk?
So far I've tried converting it with `srec_cat hex.file -Intel -Output binary.file -Binary`. I have tried to analyze the converted file with binwalk but the only results I get are:

```
SHA256 hash constants, little endian
Certificate in DER format (x509 v3), header length: 4, sequence length: 678
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Edit: after using `binwalk -Ive binary.file` I managed to extract some files. The files are not detected correctly but when I look at the files I see bits of text used on my device.

Edit 2: I don't think the firmware is compressed. But I'm not sure if it's encrypted. What's the best way to check this?

```
$ file binary.file
binary.file: data
```

Using `strings -n 10 binary.file` I get a seemingly valid list of strings.

Comment: Are you sure the firmware is not compressed/encrypted?

Comment: Can you provide either the binary or a hexdump of the first few hundred bytes of the binary, plus some of the human-readable strings returned by `strings`? Information about the device itself, such as device name, manufacturer, processor, etc would also be helpful

Answer (score 1):

**Converting your hex file to binary**

Use `xxd -p -r`. For example:

```
echo -n "deadbeef" | xxd -p -r | od -tx1
```

So, in your case, `xxd -p -r hex.file > binary.file` should do the trick.

**Encrypted or not**

If you see *unencrypted strings with messages typical to your device*, your firmware is (most probably) **not encrypted** because it is unlikely only parts would encrypted and others not.

If the unencrypted strings are typical strings from `glibc` or other libraries, then, it is uncertain.

The fact your firmware includes a certificate does not mean it is encrypted. The certificate can be used to secure communications between the IoT and a remote server for instance.

Answer (score 1):

As first step you should check the datasheet in order to get the endianness and the loading address. Then you can try to load your firmware with your favorite disassembler, for example with *radare2* yuo can use  a syntax similar to this

```
r2 -a your_arch -b bytes_num -m loading_address
```

Look at [this](https://www.radare.org/get/avrworkshops2016.pdf) for more details.

With *IDA* you should set the processor type/options and after the RAM and ROM addresses that you can get from the datasheet.

Look at [this](http://revengrazer.blogspot.de/2013/06/firmware-part-3-setting-up-ida-pro.html) example.

Comment: If it's HEX file it already contains the ROM addresses.